# The nodal lines of homogeneous harmonic polynomials divide $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $2N$ regions.

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, harmonic-functions

> Let $P_N:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a homogeneous harmonic polynomial of degree $N (N\geq1)$. Prove the nodal lines $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:P_N(x)=0\}$ divide $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $2N$ regions.

I just encountered a problem regarding the nodal line of homogeneous harmonic polynomials. I understand that the dimension of homogeneous harmonic polynomial in the problem is 2, whose proof can be found on MSE [How to calculate dimesion of homogeneous harmonic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223337/how-to-calculate-dimesion-of-homogeneous-harmonic-polynomial). Is this related to my problem? Also, I know there are some papers dealing the similar issue in the general case, but they seem too advanced for me. Could anyone write a detailed answer or suggest some basic reference?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: an example where this works is the real part of $(x+iy)^N$  Hmmm, homogeneous, my example is what is going on.

Comment: Also, despite a poor initial match, Argentina is in the next round.  The U.S. is through, drew with England.

Comment: By relavant comments above, we can actually write $P_N(x,y)=a \mathrm{R}(x+iy)^N+b \mathrm{Im}(x+iy)^N$, with real numbers $a,b$. Then how to argue next? For example, how to show the zero set of linear combination of $x^2-y^2$ and $xy$ divide the plane into four regions.